# jQuery Form verification : factorize emails validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Hye everybody,

I'm coding a game, and i have a step where user can share the game to his friends by entering several emails addresses. In this step i have to control the validity of each email address.

I'd like to factorize the script part of checking emails fields.
My functionnality works but it's a bit weird the sequence of if... else if...

Can you please watch it and give me advice.
Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/5H5ZL/1/

HTML

```
<form id="form-noel" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#ok">
    <h3>Share the game !</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="email1">Email 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="email1" name="email1" />
        <label id="error-email1" class="error"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email2">Email 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" />
        <label id="error-email2" class="error"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email3">Email 3</label>
        <input type="text" id="email3" name="email3" />
        <label id="error-email3" class="error"></label>
    </p>
    <p class="textcenter"><input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Share" /></p>
</form>
```

JS

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}

function checkEmail(emailVal, named){
    if(!isValidEmailAddress(emailVal)){
        $('#'+named).addClass('error');
        $('#error-'+named).show().attr('title', 'Merci de saisir une adresse email valide (nom@domaine.xxx)');
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        $('#'+named).removeClass('error');
        $('#error-'+named).hide().removeAttr('title');
        return true;
    }
}

$('#btn-submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var email1Val = $('#email1').val();
    var email2Val = $('#email2').val();
    var email3Val = $('#email3').val();

    if(email1Val != '' && email2Val != '' && email3Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email1Val, 'email1') && checkEmail(email2Val, 'email2') && checkEmail(email3Val, 'email3')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email1Val != '' && email2Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email1Val, 'email1') && checkEmail(email2Val, 'email2')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email1Val != '' && email3Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email1Val, 'email1') && checkEmail(email3Val, 'email3')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email2Val != '' && email2Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email2Val, 'email2') && checkEmail(email3Val, 'email3')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email1Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email1Val, 'email1')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email2Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email2Val, 'email2')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else if(email3Val != ''){
        if(checkEmail(email3Val, 'email3')){
            $('#form-noel').submit();
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#form-noel').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: why you are using if.. else here. Anyway you are submitting form with empty email values in last else condition. can you update your code how your code should behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiha !! 
I finally find the solution, refactoring the action on #btn-submit.
Here's the solution :

```
    $('#btn-submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var email1Val = $('#email1').val();
        var email2Val = $('#email2').val();
        var email3Val = $('#email3').val();
        var error = false;

        for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            if($('#email'+i).val() != ''){
                if(!checkEmail($('#email'+i).val(), 'email'+i)){
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!error){$('#form-noel').submit();}
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5H5ZL/2/